# Sum of element on certain positions in tables in List

Tags: c#, linq

Hi i have List of table of strings

```
List<string[]> PositionList23 = new List<string[]>();
```

that list contains position of document taken from file using split.

each table of string have 5 element: 
ProductCode, netvalue, vatvalue, grosvalue, vatrate

so it can look like

- xxx, 10.00, 2.00, 12.00, 20.00
- xxz, 15.00, 3.00, 18.00, 20.00
- xxy, 20.00, 1.00, 12.00, 5.00
- xyy, 40.00, 2.00, 41.00, 5.00
- xzz, 40.00, 3.20, 41.00, 8.00

I in the end i would like to have structure like :sum(netvalue), sum(vatvalue), sum(grosvalue), vatrate
so in given examlpe it would be:

- 25.00, 5.00, 30.00 , "20.00"
- 60.00, 3.00, 63.00, "5.00"
- 40.00, 3.20, 43.20, "8.00"

But please remember that list is of table of string so it do not have names like netvalue but sum have to be somehowe count based on position in table (eg netvalue is always element at 2). and that table is of string so summed elements must be somehow converted).

My code:

```
var results =
        from row in PositionList
        group row by row[3] into grp
        //orderby grp.Key
        select new
        {
            VATRate = grp.Key,
            Net = grp.Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r[0])),
            Vat = grp.Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r[1])),
            Gros = grp.Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r[2]))
        };
```

but i get FormatException in line: Net = grp.Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r[0])),

(how to paste code in comment ?)

Comment: var results =

            from row in PositionList

            group row by row[3] into grp

            //orderby grp.Key
            select new

            {

                VATRate = grp.Key,

                Net = grp.Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r[0])),

                Vat = grp.Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r[1])),

                Gros = grp.Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r[2]))

            };      


but i get FormatException in line: Net = grp.Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r[0])),

(how to paste code in comment ?)

Comment: And what doesn't work? (please edit question to include code, to read it in comments is pretty hard)

Comment: `FormatException` because `r[0]` is `xxx`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like,

```
var resultList = PositionList23.GroupBy(x => x[4]).Select(y => new string[]
                                        { 
                                            y.Sum(n => Convert.ToDecimal(n[1])).ToString(),
                                            y.Sum(v => Convert.ToDecimal(v[2])).ToString(),
                                            y.Sum(g => Convert.ToDecimal(g[3])).ToString(),
                                            y.Key.ToString()
                                        }).ToList();
```

EDIT:

Formatted the list in the way you want,

```
var resultList = PositionList23.GroupBy(x => x[4]).Select(y => new
                                        {
                                            NetValue = y.Sum(n => Convert.ToDecimal(n[1])),
                                            VatValue = y.Sum(v => Convert.ToDecimal(v[2])),
                                            GrossValue = y.Sum(g => Convert.ToDecimal(g[3])),
                                            VATRate = y.Key
                                        }).ToList();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: it almost work. The problem is that values in string are stored like :"360.0000" so it cant convert it.

Comment: ok it work cool if i add ".Replace('.',',')" after [] :) thanks

Comment: and my initial code also work if i added that. Ehh still learnig new things, thought that Convert can get values in string with . instead of , . :)